# Provide a button to explicitly save unpublished question

Tags: feature-request, draft

I was wondering if it is possible/good to provide a button on the asking page next to the "Post Your Question" or "discard" buttons, to allow a user to **save** the current content without publishing it.

Obviously, this allow a user to write down unfinished thoughts about a question, and work on and submit it later when ready.

Currently, the system has an autosave mechanism. But it's not clear how long/how often it's going to happen. And the only options seem to be either wait for the message "Draft saved" or save the question elsewhere like in notepad.

Comment: The draft system is generally pretty spotty anyway. I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: A week is how long, by the way. Manual saves won't do anything for this.

Comment: Inb4 someone already made a userscript that does this

Comment: I sometimes have to close the browser with the unfinished question. Sometimes, the draft I had got saved completely. Sometimes, only a previous version at some point in time is saved.

Comment: I don’t know if it works for questions too, but when I want to save a draft of an answer, I open the console of my browser and run `StackExchange.cardiologist.beatASAP()`, which saves a draft. Admittedly this is not very intuitive.

Comment: A lame workaround could be to post it, then quickly delete it. It's possible someone could read it in the interim, but then it will stick around as written without relying on draft saves.

Comment: @DanLowe Some people can be quick with downvotes, so it might just be better to save the markdown in notepad instead of losing reputation for a partial question.

Comment: @icktoofay There actually is an object called "cardiologist"?!? :o

Comment: @DanLowe I wonder if that could get you into trouble for deleting too many questions?